# Error: MySQL client ran out of memory

Tags: mysql, memory

Can anyone please advise me on this error...

The database has 40,000 news stories but only the fields 'story' is large, 
'old' is a numeric value 0 or 1,
'title' and 'shortstory' are very short or NULL.

any advice appreciated. This is the result of running a search database query.

```
Error: MySQL client ran out of memory 
Statement: SELECT news30_access.usehtml, old, title, story, shortstory, news30_access.name AS accessname, news30_users.user AS authorname, timestamp, news30_story.id AS newsid FROM news30_story LEFT JOIN news30_users ON news30_story.author = news30_users.uid LEFT JOIN news30_access ON news30_users.uid = news30_access.uid WHERE title LIKE ? OR story LIKE ? OR shortstory LIKE ? OR news30_users.user LIKE ? ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Don't return `story` in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is correct. There's not enough memory on the server to store the query's result, and increasing the server's memory capacity does not fix the problem's cause. You should restrict the amount of data fetched using `LIMIT`. Example: `LIMIT 100`, then in a subsequent query you can use `OFFSET` to get the next 100 results, and so on. Example: `LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100`

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is:  don't use `story` in the `SELECT` clause.

If you want the story, then limit the number of results being returned.  Start with, say, 100 results by adding:

```
limit 100
```

to the end of the query.  This will get the 100 most recent stories.

I also note that you are using `like` with `story` as well as other string columns.  You probably want to be using `match` with a full text index.  This doesn't solve your immediate problem (which is returning too much data to the client).  But, it will make your queries run faster.

To learn about full text search, start with the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: guys. sorry for absence. I removed 'story' from the script but only a blank screen was returned. [ I would be happy enough just searching the title !!  ]    by the way, even this ran incredibly slowly so im guessing something else must be wrong...